# How to test an Android class that depends on CountDownTimer

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, dependencies, tdd

I'm writing a ViewModel for an android app, and it should implement and start a CountDownTimer in order to update some UI every now and then.

I started to practice TDD lately and I wonder what architecture decisions should I make in order to make the ViewModel testable (I want the test to run rapidly without depending on real timing mechanisms).
I can't provide the CountDownTimer as a dependency because it's an abstract class that is implemented in the ViewModel itself, so I 'don't know' what implementation to give.

Generally speaking, what are the best practices for writing tests when working with frameworks that hold heavy constraints and with non-testable framework-code?

This is the code that I currently have. How do you make it testable?

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MyView myView;

    public void init(MyView myView) {
        this.myView = myView;
        new CountDownTimer(0, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                myView.updateUi(l);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                myView.updateUiFinished();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public interface MyView {
        void updateUi(long l);

        void updateUiFinished();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not mock/test code you do not own. Treat them as 3rd party dependencies that should be encapsulated behind abstractions you control. This will greater flexibility when it comes to testability. You current code is tightly coupled to the `CountDownTimer` making it more difficult to control the desired behavior when testing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not mock/test code you do not own. Treat them as 3rd party dependencies that should be encapsulated behind abstractions you control. This will greater flexibility when it comes to testability.

Your current code is tightly coupled to the `CountDownTimer` making it more difficult to control the desired behavior when testing.

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MyView myView;
    private MyCountDownTimer timer;

    public MyViewModel(MyCountDownTimer timer) {
        this.timer = timer;
    }

    public void init(MyView myView) {
        this.myView = myView;
        timer.attach(this.myView);
        timer.start();
    }

    public interface MyView {
        void updateUi(long l);
        void updateUiFinished();
    }

    public interface MyCountDownTimer { 
        void attach(MyView view);
        void start();
        void cancel();
    }
}

public class DefaultUiUpdateTimer extends MyViewModel.MyCountDownTimer {
    private CountDownTimer timer;

    public void attach(MyViewModel.MyView myView) {
        timer = new CountDownTimer(0, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                myView.updateUi(l);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                myView.updateUiFinished();
            }
        };
    }   

    public void start() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public void cancel() {
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

`MyViewModel` is now decoupled from the `CountDownTimer` as the creation of the instance has been inverted and an explicit dependency injected into the constructor. You could just as easily passed it in the the `init` method along with the view instead

```
public void init(MyView myView, MyCountDownTimer timer) {
    this.myView = myView;
    this.timer = timer;
    timer.attach(this.myView);
    timer.start();
}
```

the anonymous `CountDownTimer` subclass is technically an implementation concern which, now that it has been extracted and encapsulated in its on concern allows you to do what ever you see fit with the view.

For testing the view model, mock/stubs/fakes can be passed to the subject of the test and desired behavior configured to allow tests to be exercised to completion.

Comment: Very nice. Precise, sound. Just nice!

Comment: @Nkosi how do you test myView.updateUi(l) was called?  ps: I like your idea to wrap 3rd party stuff to make it easier for testing.

Comment: @sudocoder that depends on the test case. Can you clarify the case you are referring to. Is the view the subject under test or the view model?